# git - unable to clone Host key verification failed. fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I am trying to clone a repo from bitbucket.

here's what error I am getting

> Host key verification failed.
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

As I understand it is `ssh` related issue so I am following [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html) tutorial to add the key to my bitbucket account and I am successfully able to do the same.

But I am still unable to clone it, not sure what the issue is. Can someone help.

PS: It does look like a duplicate question but been failing to get it work from the earlier answers from other questions.

Comment: What else does it say? There's more in your output than what you've posted here.